# Unable to locate freeimage after install of mahotas in Python

Tags: python, installation, package, mahotas

Hi I am new to Python and am following the [Python Image Tutorial](http://pythonvision.org/basic-tutorial).

The following executes with no errors after installing the packages described in the tutorial

```
import numpy
import scipy
import pylab
import pymorph
import mahotas
from scipy import ndimage
```

However when I try reading an image

```
image = mahotas.imread('picture_file.jpg')
```

I get

> > > image = mahotas.imread('image_file.jpg')
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >           File "", line 1, in 
> > >           File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mahotas-0.6.4-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/mahotas/**init**.py", line 68, in imread
> > >           raise ImportError('mahotas.imread dependends on freeimage. Could not find it. Error was: %s' % e)
> > >           ImportError: mahotas.imread dependends on freeimage. Could not find it. Error was: mahotas.freeimage: could not find libFreeImage in any of the following directories: 
> > >           '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mahotas-0.6.4-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/mahotas', '/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/opt/local/lib'

I tried installing FreeImagePy and can import it with no problems but it does not help. I have tried adding to the Python path using package sys but not help either.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that all the packages except pymorph and mahotas was installed
on my linux box doing '*sudo apt-get install package_name*' while pymorph and mahotas was installed by downloading and doing '*sudo python setup.py install*'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer for more recent versions of mahotas**

Mahotas itself does not have the functionality to read in images. imread is just a wrapper around one of 3 backends:

1. mahotas-imread (i.e., https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imread)
2. FreeImage
3. matplotlib (which only supports PNG & JPEG)

Thus, you need to install one of the packages above. Freeimage can be installed on Ubuntu as described below.

If you are running on Windows, you may wish to try [Christoph Gohlke’s packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mahotas).

**Original answer (for older versions of mahotas)**

You need to install freeimage to be able to use `mahotas.imread` (everything else will actually work without it, it's an optional dependency). This is not a Python package per se, just a regular library.

I don't know what distribution you are in, but try looking for a freeimage package. On debian/ubuntu, you can just do:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreeimage3
```

You will have a file `libfreeimage.so` in `/usr/lib` or in a similar place and everything will work.

Comment: That was kind of a Homer moment for me when reading this. Thanks.

Comment: The next version will have a more descriptive error message as a result of your question (it's already so on the github version).